# Ajax loader freezes

Tags: ajax, jquery

My ajax loader freezes the browser and throws an JavaScript error (stop script or continue). I tried changing async to true/false but no luck. I'm creating div tables on success.

```
$.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "getschedules",
          data: '{"StartingDate": "' + startdate + '", "EndingDate": "' + enddate + '"}',                   
          contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
          async: true,
          dataType: "json"
          }).done(function (response) {
          adc.createTable(response);
          }).fail(function () {
          })
        }
```

Comment: Are you sure the problem isn't `adc.createTable(response);` and not your ajax request? (comment it out to test) How big is the json response?

Comment: It does not freeze when i search for 1 day. If I search for more days, it freezes.

Comment: that doesn't tell us anything other than that it freezing has something to do with the amount of data you are returning, which we pretty much already know.

Comment: I agree with @KevinB - The problem is likely caused by the `createTable` function.  Show us an example of the JSON that gets returned when you encounter the problem.  And maybe show us the code of the `createTable` function.

Comment: I would post the `createTable()` function code for review.